# Generically accessing attributes on arbitrary objects at runtime

Tags: python

Let's say we have an arbitrary object of an unknown type and we want to access an equally arbitrary attribute associated with this object, queried as a string name. I am looking for a best-practice approach for obtaining this value.

In pseudo-code/Python, the current strategy I am considering is along these lines:

```
def access_attribute(obj, attr):
    if type(obj) == types.FunctionType:
        return access_attribute(obj(), attr)
    elif type(obj) == types.DictType:
        return obj.get(attr)
    # ... etc.
```

A couple items to consider:

- What happens if the attribute does not exist on the object? I am okay raising an exception.
- The attribute may be deeply nested.

I figure this is the kind of problem that must be solved by programming languages and DSL interpreters, but I don't know of a standard/commonly accepted best practice.

The idea of passing custom stored DSL/code to `eval` at runtime along with the object has been broached, but I want to avoid this particular solution for now and prefer a Pythonic one.

Comment: I too am interested in an answer to this question. I've run into multiple cases where having the ability to access attributes via configuration would be beneficial, but have run into difficulty with the many types in complex Object hierarchies...

Comment: Not sure if there is a best practice. As far as existing approaches go, I have worked with the `Accessor` class in django-tables2 ([code](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/utils.py)) which does a pretty generic and nested attribute lookup by name (attributes, dict-keys, list-indexes, 0-arg methods, etc.).

Comment: @schwobaseggl thanks for the reference to django-tables2. The Accessor code is definitely along similar lines. There may very well be ideas there to borrow and reflect upon.

Comment: What's you mean by *The attribute may be deeply nested* exactly?

Comment: You should also mention how you want the client to interact, i.e. the API.  I second the django-tables2 too (had looked at it).  But it, like Template substitution code with nested look ups, expects the path to be a string.  Ditto `operator.attrgetter`.  Also, if it's nested, can you switch higher levels from attributes to dicts?  `foo.a[b].c`?

Comment: Also, if you look at Python 2.7 operator module, it has type checking functions (for example, **(operator.isMappingType**).  Which is deprecated and doc recommends `isinstance(x, collections.Mapping)`.  I used that for something similar to your work and it seems more powerful than `== types.DictType` probing.

Comment: So what should happen if a name is available both as an attribute and a dictionary key? What if you wanted to access *indices in a sequence*? What if an object is both callable and has direct attributes? What if a callable raises an exception when called (be it because arguments are missing or other reasons)?

Comment: On the whole, the answer to the question 'what is the best practice' is *don't do this*. Some template languages take a narrower approach and allow both attribute access and dictionary key lookups, but are pretty explicit in what takes precedence. I have never seen *calls* included in such traversal. At any rate, this is way too broad a question anyway.

Answer (score -1):

[`getattr(object, name[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#getattr) seems to answer at least the first half of your question and this point:

> What happens if the attribute does not exist on the object? I am okay raising an exception.

I'd argue that this is a best practice since it's part of the standard library.

Regarding your second point:

> The attribute may be deeply nested.

A solution would be to use [`dir(object)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) (which will list all the attributes of an object) and loop over those for non-dict objects, but i'm less confident about the 'best-practice' aspect of this solution.

Comment: I think this directly ignores the question regarding the different types of access that would be used and how to best determine how to traverse the object structure.